# Git commit is not squashing my commits in correct order

Tags: git

I have tried following commands

```
git add .
git commit -m "something new"
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

However the my most recent commit is coming at bottom

Like:

```
pick 01dbd46 something
pick 29e6002 something new
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly fine.
Git shows the oldest commit at the top in interactive rebase. (This is unlike the default for git log and other commands, so we understand your confusion.)

If you do something like

```
pick 01dbd46 something
squash 29e6002 something new
```

`something new` will be squashed into `something`

Comment: kk, actually i am confused about this concept. When i have used the Squashing before it is like this                                                                      pick        29e6002 something new                                                                        squash   01dbd46 something                                                                                 so in which order the commits would come and if our repository is already updated then we need to do?? this : git rebase -i HEAD~2 or   git rebase -i HEAD~1